# Sort dynamically created div based on their id using jquery

Tags: jquery

**Sort dynamically created div based on their id.**

I have the `html` structure like below:

```
<div id="res">
  <div id="3">text 3</div>
  <div id="4">text 4</div>
  <div id="1">text 1</div>
  <div id="2">text 2</div>
</div>
```

These `html are created dynamically`.

```
$("#res").append("<div id="+i+">text "+i+"</div>");
```

The order may vary(it is created using **ajax** in **for** loop). **Unluckly divs are displayed in random order**.(I don't know the reason).

However after appending the `divs` to the `res` `div`, I decided to sort the divs in correct order based on their `id`.

So the expected result should be:

```
<div id="res">
  <div id="1">text 1</div>
  <div id="2">text 2</div>
  <div id="3">text 3</div>
  <div id="4">text 4</div>
</div>
```

How can I do this?

I tried

```
$("#resdiv").tsort("",{attr:"id"});
```

and

```
$('#res> div').toArray().sort( function(a,b) { a.id - b.id } );
```

But nothing worked...

Someone can help me..

Comment: $('#res div').sort(function(x, y){return $(x).attr('id')-$(y).attr('id')});

Comment: _I don't know the reason_.......this one you have to debug. `.append()` works as it should.

Comment: Why you don't want to do this with javascript? `sort()` method is available in javascript not in jQuery.

Comment: `$('#res').html( $('#res > div').sort(function(x,y){return parseInt(x.id) > parseInt(y.id) ? 1 : -1}) );`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following

```
$("#res div").sort(function (elem1, elem2) {
    return parseInt(elem1.id) > parseInt(elem2.id);
}).each(function () {
    var element = $(this);
    element.remove();
    $(element).appendTo("#res");
});
```

**Explanation** -  You have first sorted the elements on based of `id` and then iterate over those elements so as to first remove them from html (irrespective of the position) and then appending it back to the container element (this time sorted)

Comment: thanks nikhil..its really helped me..

Comment: @next2u - Feel good to help you

Answer (score 0):

You can use native JavaScript **[`sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)**

```js
var $res = $('#res');
$('div', $res).sort(function(a, b) {
  return parseInt(a.id, 10) - parseInt(b.id, 10);
}).appendTo($res);
// For updating the order you need to append it, which updates elements order
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="res">
  <div id="3">text 3</div>
  <div id="4">text 4</div>
  <div id="1">text 1</div>
  <div id="2">text 2</div>
</div>
```