# Jquery sort spans inside div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I ve dynamically generated spans which are inside a div.
so structure is like this:

```
<div class="col-12 bk_slot_div1 ">
  <span>
    <span class="bk_slot_div" style="padding: 6px 11px;background: #FFFFFF;font-size: 14px;color: #555555;text-align: center;border: 1px solid #979797;border-radius: 4px;cursor: pointer" id="8" t-att-data-slot_plans="12:45">12:45</span>
  </span>
  <span>
    <span class="disabled disable_msg" style="padding: 6px 11px;background: #e9ecef;font-size: 14px;color: #555555;text-align: center;border: 1px solid #979797;border-radius: 4px;cursor: pointer" id="7" t-att-data-slot_plans="12:00">12:00</span>
  </span>
</div>
```

shows like this:

[image]

From jquery:

```
var bk_class = $('.bk_slot_div1');
bk_class.append('<span><span class="bk_slot_div" style="padding: 6px 11px;background: #FFFFFF;font-size: 14px;color: #555555;text-align: center;border: 1px solid #979797;border-radius: 4px;cursor: pointer" id="8" t-att-data-slot_plans="12:45">12:45</span></span><span><span class="disabled disable_msg" style="padding: 6px 11px;background: #e9ecef;font-size: 14px;color: #555555;text-align: center;border: 1px solid #979797;border-radius: 4px;cursor: pointer" id="7" t-att-data-slot_plans="12:00">12:00</span></span>');
```

when appying sort:

```
$(".bk_slot_div1 span > span").sort(function (elem1, elem2) {
    return parseInt(elem1.id) > parseInt(elem2.id);
}).each(function () {
    var element = $(this);
    element.remove();
    $(element).appendTo(".bk_slot_div1");
});
```

It produces multiple repetition of same span. Also the parent span is gone missing. Any idea what i am doing wrong? Sorry for bad English.

[image]

This post is also related to my requirement. Bt i still failed to find what i m doing wrong.

[Sort dynamically created div based on their id using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35198302/sort-dynamically-created-div-based-on-their-id-using-jquery)

Example

```js
var bk_class = $('.bk_slot_div1');
bk_class.append('<span><span class="bk_slot_div" style="padding: 6px 11px;background: #FFFFFF;font-size: 14px;color: #555555;text-align: center;border: 1px solid #979797;border-radius: 4px;cursor: pointer" id="8" t-att-data-slot_plans="12:45">12:45</span></span><span><span class="disabled disable_msg" style="padding: 6px 11px;background: #e9ecef;font-size: 14px;color: #555555;text-align: center;border: 1px solid #979797;border-radius: 4px;cursor: pointer" id="7" t-att-data-slot_plans="12:00">12:00</span></span>');

$(".bk_slot_div1 span > span").sort(function (elem1, elem2) {
    return parseInt(elem1.id) > parseInt(elem2.id);
}).each(function () {
    var element = $(this);
    element.remove();
    $(element).appendTo(".bk_slot_div1");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-12 bk_slot_div1 ">
  <span>
    <span class="bk_slot_div" style="padding: 6px 11px;background: #FFFFFF;font-size: 14px;color: #555555;text-align: center;border: 1px solid #979797;border-radius: 4px;cursor: pointer" id="8" t-att-data-slot_plans="12:45">12:45</span>
  </span>
  <span>
    <span class="disabled disable_msg" style="padding: 6px 11px;background: #e9ecef;font-size: 14px;color: #555555;text-align: center;border: 1px solid #979797;border-radius: 4px;cursor: pointer" id="7" t-att-data-slot_plans="12:00">12:00</span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Offtopic: `t-att-data-slot_plans` is an invalid HTML5 attribute. Using inline style attribute is also a really bad idea. CSS should be used instead of `&nbsp;&nbsp;`

Comment: actually my framework is other. It has nothing to do with that. I m using odoo

Comment: You're targeting the inner SPANs with this selector `".bk_slot_div1 span > span"`.

Comment: can u suggest solution plz?

Comment: my inner span has ids so how can i compare the inner span with the other span?

Comment: Off-topic: consider using css classes instead of huge duplicated style=

Comment: This is because you are using `append`. https://jsfiddle.net/ztgm2spu/
Which basically adds new spans to existing ones.

Comment: @ent3 the statement is not entirely correct. He's removing the INNER spans and appending them to the outer parent getting this result `<ps><ps><cs><cs>` instead of the sorted `<ps <cs>><ps <cs>>`

Comment: bt why its repeating? my main question?

Comment: @ent3 if i remove sort part it does not shows any duplicates.

Comment: It's not *repeating*. You're targeting the `span > span` and never moving the wrapping parent SPANs. Only the targeted (child) ones.

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]?   I copied your code to a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p5f1gkxz/) and it runs the sort, but doesn't sort or duplicate.

Comment: can i share url as an example?

Comment: .appendTo / .append with an element will *move* an existing element, it will not duplicate it.  If you use an html string, it will create a new element.

Comment: *can i share url as an example?* ideally, all code needs to be in the question rather than on a third party site, though jsfiddle/codepen are accepted for large amounts of code.  If it's your own site then it's not normally of any use (as it will change making the question redundant for future reference) - it'll probably be ok for at this point (as you *do* have a lot of code in the question)

Comment: yes i know its nt good idea. Bt for giving appropiat example. I ve no other choice

https://mirestaurant-stg-5197316.dev.odoo.com/book/Lunch/1?debug=assets

Comment: Select any Monday slot. On site i ve not added sort code bt giving u understanding that i m trying to sort Time Slot. That is 12:45 and 12:00 to 12:00 to 12:45

Comment: This is where generating an [mcve] will help.  By providing the minimum code to *reproduce* the issue, you'll likely find your issue.  Also *I've not added sort code* - so is it working/not working on your site?   If there's no sort code and it doesn't work, then sort's not the issue, if there's no sort code so there's no functionality, what are we looking at?

Comment: shall i remove from question abt my experiment and ask a simple question how to sort inner span with other in span?

Comment: <div class="col-12 bk_slot_div1 ">
  <span>
    <span class="bk_slot_div" style="padding: 6px 11px;background: #FFFFFF;font-size: 14px;color: #555555;text-align: center;border: 1px solid #979797;border-radius: 4px;cursor: pointer" id="8" t-att-data-slot_plans="12:45">12:45</span>
  </span>
  <span>
    <span class="disabled disable_msg" style="padding: 6px 11px;background: #e9ecef;font-size: 14px;color: #555555;text-align: center;border: 1px solid #979797;border-radius: 4px;cursor: pointer" id="7" t-att-data-slot_plans="12:00">12:00</span>
  </span>
</div>

Comment: Your question seems ok, just needs details / a working snippet that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: TBH where do you get the 12:45/12:00 dates from?   You might find it easier to sort them *before* they're added to the HTML - ie on the server.

Comment: @user3162878  <div class="col-12 bk_slot_div1 ">
    
</div> remove all child from Parent div in HTML then append using jQuery as u did ,repetition will be removed

Comment: @freedomn-m that time is saved as string in database and they have id like 8,7

Comment: I'm not sure why you think the sort is duplicating.  Let's step through your code:  1) some HTML with some spans.  2) some jquery that *adds the same spans again* 3) a sort that has no impact on the 4 spans already there.   Remove the jquery that adds new spans if the spans are already in the HTML or clear out the existing spans before adding new ones.  Or I'm misreading the issue and it's not that you have duplicate spans, but that they're not sorting.   Going through the comments above, most of them are regarding duplicate spans.  Please clarify the **exact issue you are having**.

Comment: Also, why don't you sort by time (`12:45` etc. - instead of ID) if that's actually the desired?! If you're going to use numeric IDs like that it's matter of time and you'll have duplicated IDs in your application.

Comment: @freedomn-m if u can debug on browser. The opening website_calendar_booking folder then in static/src/js/booking_website.js and just add a breakpoint at 224 so that all bk_class gets load and just apply my jquery on console u will see it duplicates. On selecting ESC and then again selecting Slot like Monday they will be more duplicate

Answer (score 0):

- When doing `.each()` make sure to `.append()` the wrapping **parent SPANs** of the sorted SPANs by using `.parent()`.
- Alternatively, **sort the wrapper SPANs instead** (given their child SPANs ID). Then you only need `.appendTo()` instead of foreaching every child one by one.
- Make sure to return an integer in your `.sort()` method:

Example 1: **Sorting parent SPANs**:

```js
const $bkSlot1 = $(".bk_slot_div1");

$("> span", $bkSlot1)
  .sort((a, b) => $("> span", a).attr("id") - $("> span", b).attr("id"))
  .appendTo($bkSlot1);
```

```css
.bk_slot_div1 span>span {
  padding: 6px 11px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #555555;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #979797;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer
}
```

```html
<div class="col-12 bk_slot_div1">
  <span>
    <span id="8">8</span>
  </span>
    <span>
    <span id="2">2</span>
  </span>
  <span>
    <span id="5">5</span>
  </span>
  <span>
    <span id="7">7</span>
  </span>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Example 2: **Sorting children SPANs**:

```js
const $bkSlot1 = $(".bk_slot_div1");

$("span > span", $bkSlot1)
  .sort((a, b) => a.id - b.id)
  .each((i, el) => $bkSlot1.append($(el).parent()));
```

```css
.bk_slot_div1 span>span {
  padding: 6px 11px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #555555;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #979797;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer
}
```

```html
<div class="col-12 bk_slot_div1">
  <span>
    <span id="8">8</span>
  </span>
    <span>
    <span id="2">2</span>
  </span>
  <span>
    <span id="5">5</span>
  </span>
  <span>
    <span id="7">7</span>
  </span>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I would highly discourage to use numeric (non-prefixed) IDs. Get the habit and it's matter of time you'll end up having **duplicated IDs** in your application.

Use the **time** as a sort factor instead (the one stored inside a valid HTML5 data-* attribute):

```js
const $bkSlot1 = $(".bk_slot_div1");

$("> span", $bkSlot1)
  .sort((a, b) => {
    const timeA = $("> span", a).data("time");
    const timeB = $("> span", b).data("time");
    return timeA.localeCompare(timeB);
  })
  .appendTo($bkSlot1);
```

```css
.bk_slot_div1 span>span {
  padding: 6px 11px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #555555;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #979797;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer
}
```

```html
<div class="col-12 bk_slot_div1">
  <span>
    <span data-time="12:00">12:00</span>
  </span>
  <span>
    <span data-time="14:15">14:15</span>
  </span>
  <span>
    <span data-time="10:00">10:00</span>
  </span>
    <span>
    <span data-time="10:45">10:45</span>
  </span>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: ok thnx let me understand ur solution

Comment: @user3162878 added another better example that uses the `data-time` attribute for sorting by-time.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue in your code is because you're sorting the *child* `span` elements, not the *parent* `span` elements.

The `each()` loop is also redundant as you can just `append()` the content back to its original parent after sorting it.

Finally, you should return an integer value from the `sort()` handler function, not a boolean:

```js
let $container = $('.bk_slot_div1');

$container.children('span').sort((a, b) => {
  let aId = parseInt($(a).children('span').prop('id'), 10);
  let bId = parseInt($(b).children('span').prop('id'), 10);
  return aId > bId ? 1 : aId < bId ? -1 : 0;
}).appendTo($container);
```

```css
.bk_slot_div {
  padding: 6px 11px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #555555;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #979797;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-12 bk_slot_div1 ">
  <span>
    <span class="bk_slot_div" id="8" t-att-data-slot_plans="12:45">12:45</span>
  </span>
  <span>
    <span class="disabled disable_msg" id="7" t-att-data-slot_plans="12:00">12:00</span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Did u try removing > sign and additional span from your selector?

```
$(".bk_slot_div1 span ")
```

Example:

```js
var bk_class = $('.bk_slot_div1');
bk_class.append('<span><span class="bk_slot_div" style="padding: 6px 11px;background: #FFFFFF;font-size: 14px;color: #555555;text-align: center;border: 1px solid #979797;border-radius: 4px;cursor: pointer" id="8" t-att-data-slot_plans="12:45">12:45</span></span><span><span class="disabled disable_msg" style="padding: 6px 11px;background: #e9ecef;font-size: 14px;color: #555555;text-align: center;border: 1px solid #979797;border-radius: 4px;cursor: pointer" id="7" t-att-data-slot_plans="12:00">12:00</span></span>');

$(".bk_slot_div1 span").sort(function (elem1, elem2) {
    return parseInt(elem1.id) > parseInt(elem2.id);
}).each(function () {
    var element = $(this);
    element.remove();
    $(element).appendTo(".bk_slot_div1");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-12 bk_slot_div1 ">
  <span>
    <span class="bk_slot_div" style="padding: 6px 11px;background: #FFFFFF;font-size: 14px;color: #555555;text-align: center;border: 1px solid #979797;border-radius: 4px;cursor: pointer" id="8" t-att-data-slot_plans="12:45">12:45</span>
  </span>
  <span>
    <span class="disabled disable_msg" style="padding: 6px 11px;background: #e9ecef;font-size: 14px;color: #555555;text-align: center;border: 1px solid #979797;border-radius: 4px;cursor: pointer" id="7" t-att-data-slot_plans="12:00">12:00</span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you noticed that the selector you're suggesting has no ID?